# Simple script not printing

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm trying to sort a collection, and then print the first 5 docs to make sure it has worked:

```
#!/user/bin/env python

import pymongo

# Establish a connection to the mongo database.
connection = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost')

# Get a handle to the students database.
db = connection.school
students = db.students


def order_homework():

    projection = {'scores': {'$elemMatch': {'type': 'homework'}}}
    cursor = students.find({}, projection)

    # Sort each item's scores.
    for each in cursor:
        each['scores'].sort()

    # Sort by _id.
    cursor = sorted(cursor, key=lambda x: x['_id'])

    # Print the first five items.
    count = 0
    for each in cursor:
        print(each)
        count += 1
        if count == 5:
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    order_homework()
```

When I run this, nothing prints.
If I take out the sorts, then it prints.
Each sort works when run individually.

Please teach me what I'm doing wrong / educate me.

Comment: if you don't have no errors and no prints in the same time means that the loop hasn't been executed. So take a look on what is inside the cursor - perhaps it doesn't have any entries inside - most likely it is just empty.

Comment: what is `cursor` - list or iterator? iterator after first iteration shows nothing.

Comment: ``cursor`` contains 200 documents in the format shown here: https://gist.github.com/BigGingerJake/82d9dc89d534ff331e0783d2c4fc6e42  if I run the code for ``projection`` and ``cursor`` variables independently within a mongo client I can see that ``cursor`` does contain the documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to treat the cursor like a list, which you can iterate several times from the start. PyMongo cursors don't act that way - once you've iterated it in `for each in cursor`, the cursor is completed and you can't iterate it again.

You can turn the cursor into a list like:

```
data = list(students.find({}, projection))
```

For efficiency, get results pre-sorted from MongoDB:

```
list(students.find({}, projection).sort('_id'))
```

This sends the sort criterion to the server, which then streams the results back to you pre-sorted, instead of requiring you to do it client-side. Now delete your "Sort by _id" line below.